# Get tierprice list in list.phtml

Tags: magento2, price

I want to echo the tier prices on the `list.phtml`?

I have taken a look at `tier_prices.phtml` but the code can't just be copypasted, because then you'd get a notice error and it'll stop working.

`$tierprice = $_product->getData('tier_price');` just gives you the "lowest price" for the specific product.

How can I achieve to get the tierprices displayed on `list.phtml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('tier_price');

if ($attribute) {
   $attribute->getBackend()->afterLoad($_product);
   $tierPrices = $_product->getTierPrice();
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand why, but this has worked nicely.

Answer (score -1):

You can include `tier_price.phtml` file in your `list.phtml` file. Try to include it by code similar to below code:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('path_to your_phtml_file')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: What would be the propper way to include a unmodified tier_prices.phtml? `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/...`?

Comment: You are using magento 1.x or 2??

Comment: If you want to include in magento 1.9.x, then you can use the code which I have mentioned above.

Comment: If you want to include in magento 1.9.x, then you can use the code which I have mentioned above. If you want to include it in any phtml file inside catalog, then you can call it through <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>

Comment: See question tags, `magento2`. Thanks for the inut anyway. :)